# Grafana Docker Plesk SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, grafana, plesk

I have the following problem. I run Grafana in a Docker container via Plesk Obsidian and now I want to reach Grafana via https. Of course I want to use the already created certificate of my domain.
For that I have added with volume mapping the Docker directory **"/cert"** to **"/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/DOMAIN"** containing the .pem files.

**And among others the following environment variables:**

```
GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE = /cert/fullchain.pem
GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL = https 
GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY = /cert/privkey.pem
```

But now I get the message "***open /cert/fullchain.pem: permission denied***", why this happens is of course obvious to me - but how should I fix it?

**The permissions of the directory /live and the /DOMAIN directory are:**

```
drwx------ 4 psaadm psaadm 4,0K Feb 20 10:54 live
```

**The permissions of the files in /DOMAIN are:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 psaadm psaadm  37 Feb 16 18:14 cert.pem -> ../../archive/_plesk_domain/cert2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 psaadm psaadm  38 Feb 16 18:14 chain.pem -> ../../archive/_plesk_domain/chain2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 psaadm psaadm  42 Feb 16 18:14 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/_plesk_domain/fullchain2.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 psaadm psaadm  40 Feb 16 18:14 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/_plesk_domain/privkey2.pem
```

If I copy the **privkey.pem** and the **fullchain.pem** into another directory, then give the directory **`chown 472:root & chmod 777`** and the files **`chmod +r`**, then it works. But I do not want to copy the files every three months and most of all I want to have these files only once.

I'm not sure what effect it would have if I assign a different user to the certificate type files or similar, or if I should add the user (But which one is it when using a docker?) to the psaadm group?